# A function within a loop, with unchanged arguments

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop

I want to call a function within a loop. The function takes three parameters. I want two of them to stay unchanged within a loop while only the third is affected through my loop.

**Edited Version :** Here is a sample code:

```
void Function(int v1, int v2, int v3) {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    int a;
    int b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Function(int a, int b, i)
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I compile this code :

```
error: 
      expected expression Function(int v1, int v2, i)....
```

Is there a way to realize my idea?

Comment: `Function(int v1, int v2, i)`, you do not need `int`s here.

Comment: **go ahead editing your question**, remove `int`s from calling method which is `main()`

Comment: still not completed, read my answer then apply what it is written there.

Comment: **Excellent.** Highly likelihood you don't understand what's going on under the hood?? To do it, look under the hood meaning **COMMENCE READING A C BOOK**

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Absolute-Beginners-Guide-3rd/dp/0789751984/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0789751984&pd_rd_r=GFYGENHMVVMEFRJRWJAV&pd_rd_w=fsrdd&pd_rd_wg=uUGTb&psc=1&refRID=GFYGENHMVVMEFRJRWJAV

Comment: I will . Thank you for your input and suggestions . It really helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. It's really good book. Read it.

Comment: Dont edit your question to fix the errors you were originally asking for. In its current state your question literally makes no sense, because there is no way the code you show could produce the error you report.

Comment: Yes I will fix this right now

Comment: i just did it already

Comment: Lol.  A list of C++ books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: btw I dont understand why snr encouraged you to edit the question and fix the errors.... @snr please dont do that. Questions are for question and for broken code, fixed code goes in the answers

Comment: @user463035818 < Sir, he started to edit the question from its backbone(s), what should I have done in this case ?

Comment: @user463035818 Sorry I will consider this in the future

Comment: @snr i dont really understand why you mean (backbones??), but you should not have told him to edit the question to incorporate the code fixes, because this makes the question completely useless on a Q&A site where question should contain the question and not the answers

Comment: I wanted just to correct the obvious mistakes, that I did not realize while  writing the question ...like missing void.

Comment: @snr maybe "go ahead editing your question" was sarcasm, in this case i didnt get it and seems like OP too ;)

Comment: @xava Don't worry, things will improve as you get a better feel for the site.

Comment: btw I am not trying to play the "i know how this site works"-police, I am also just a user trying to get the best out of it. Just wanted to give advice ;)

Comment: @snr Question is tagged c++.  Stop bickering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot, I think you don't know, a host of things. Keep track of the comments. However, you have to read a C book for beginners.

```
//whereIsReturnTypeofTheFunction ???
void Function(int v1, int v2, int v3) {};

int main () {

    // you need variables to be passed to Function
    int a;
    int b;

    // for condition is vetted by looking i, not int, in the middle
    for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
        Function(a,  b, i); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong syntax, and that's why you are getting the error.

When **declaring** a function, you specify the *type* of the parameters (and don't forget the return type):

```
void Function(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
    // your function body here
};
```

When **invoking** a function, you simply pass the parameters:

```
Function(1, 2, 3);
```

In your case, the compiler thought you were trying to declare another function, while in the body of another.

So, in the end, and assuming v1 and v2 are already defined, you need to write your main as

```
int main () { 

  // don't forget to define v1 and v2
  int v1 = 10;
  int v2 = 20;   

  for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
    Function(v1, v2, i)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where is the return type of `Function` ?? I think it is not the adequate answer. If `Function` was return type, where would be its name?

Comment: I completely agree... your answer is much better, so I didn't fix mine.
But I'll fix it now... shouldn't leave a misleading answer

Comment: Done, but go easy on the new guy who asked the question. Clearly he's new on the site and is still learning programming

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I've already put it in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
void Function(int v1, int v2, int v3) { };

int main () { 
  int v1 = 0;
  int v2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Function(v1, v2, i);
  }
}
```

Some problems with your code:

```
for (int i=0; int <5; i++)
```

Here you use `int` instead of `i` for the run condition.

```
Function(int v1, int v2, i)
```

Here you declare v1 and v2, but they are undefined (they have a unknown value). Declare and initialize them before the loop. Also no semicolon at the end.